# Streaming Games from PC to TV

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming, tv, gaming

Currently my PC (Running Windows 7) is in my bedroom, while my TV is in my living room. I was wondering if there was a way to play my Steam games on my TV? Some of the more obvious solutions are one very long HDMI cable or moving my computer to the living room, which are two roads I don't want to go down.

Other viable options are buying a [Steam Machine](http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamMachines/). The issue however is not all my Steam Games are compatible with the SteamOS or Linux. Not to mention that I will then have two systems (The Steam Machine and my PC) to worry about upgrading once their hardware eventually becomes out dated. I've scoured the web and found a few things I can connect directly into my TV's HDMI port which allows it to wirelessly pick up on the game my PC streams to it, however further reading tells me that such things are prone to lag.

Is there any technology that will allow me to stream and play my Steam games on my TV without lag or lengthy wires that are tripping hazards?

Comment: You are aware that you can use a Steam Machine to recieve the stream from your Windows machine once that feature is stable ( its in beta ).

Comment: Did not know that! I'll have to read up on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without lag

If you're referring to Miracast adapters, you are right that -- depending on the network conditions and the quality of the adapter -- these *can sometimes* experience lag and frame drops. Ideally you would have a Miracast or WiDi setup that you've carefully configured so that it doesn't interfere with other wireless in your house (bluetooth, WiFi, etc). since it operates on the same frequency bands. There may also be Miracast adapters that advertise a longer than average operating range, or have a directional antenna that you could tune to point right at your PC.

> lengthy wires that are tripping hazards

Run the cable(s) under the carpet or along the side of the wall and tie them down; problem solved :) But seriously this is the more fool-proof way to go about it with as many restrictions as you're placing on this setup (can't move PC, can't have HTPC, can't have SteamBox, etc.)

Also, no matter what you do, you'll need to have some kind of WiFi based keyboard and mouse... Logitech Unifying stuff, for example. Do not try to use bluetooth equipment because it will not be able to handle the distance between your living room and the bedroom, especially if there isn't a line of sight (walls/floor between them).

My recommendation would be:

1. Try (hard!) to work out the logistics of getting your cables installed neatly, either under carpet, in the wall, or something other than just laying it in the walkway.
2. Failing that, buy a bunch of Miracast adapters from a store that has a good return policy, and keep returning them until you find one that works.

If you aren't willing to go down either of these routes, then the answer to your question is **no**, there is no way to do this, you are completely stuck and will be unable to resolve your problem in any way, shape, or form.