# Hardware recommendations : PC to connect to TV for movies and games

Tags: hardware-rec

I like to watch movies and to play video games, from my sofa.
I happen to have a lot of good movies on my old desk computer (whose disk is almost full), as well as a lot of good games in my Steam library. However I cannot really enjoy them while sitting at my desk (that I associate with work).

I am considering the following solutions:

- For movies, a "Media Center", a machine with enough disk space to store a lot of movies whose video/audio output I can connect to my TV.
- For games, a "Steam Machine", or a PC with specs good enough to provide a satisfying experience with recent games, that I also want to connect to my TV (I am not sure if SteamOS would be a good system in that case).

As I do not have a lot of room left next to the TV, I am looking for a compact hardware that could fulfill both those requirements. **What kind of hardware should I look into ?**

I am not aware of the recent trends, so I would also like to know if there are keywords that could help me more. For example, would a "mini barebone PC" be something compatible with a high-end GPU ? Can a "Steam Machine" be used as a media server ? What exactly is a "game streaming" machine?

---

*Possibly related question(s):

 - [Streaming Games from PC to TV](https://superuser.com/questions/722873/streaming-games-from-pc-to-tv)

 - [Recommended small form factor gaming PCs?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42)*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Alienware's X51. It comes with windows, doesn't take much room and can be configured to fulfil your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you know if it would be possible to add a disk, or to replace the one provided with the machine (biggest option was 2TB from what I saw on their site). Also in the future would upgrading the GPU be an easy task?

Comment: @wil It is easily possible to replace the disk, but for more than 2TB I would advise you to buy an external hard drive. The GPU can be upgraded, just buy one that fits the case. ;) 
Btw [Steam Alpha](http://www.dell.com/us/p/alienware-alpha/pd?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&fl=p&~ck=mn) also comes with Windows 8.1.